# Relationship between the gradient of parametrized scalar-valued function and its own gradient?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, jacobian

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $y=f(x)$ and $x=[x_1,\dots, x_n]^T$. Suppose we reparametrize $f(x)$ such that $z_i=c_ix_i$ to define a new scalar-valued function $g=f(z)$ where $z=[z_1,\dots, z_n]^T=[c_1x_1,\dots, c_nx_n]^T$.

**Question:** How can one write $\nabla_c(f(z))\mid_{c=[1,\dots,1]^T}$ based on the original function $f(x)$?

**My try:**

One can write the jacobian of $f(z)$ as follows:

$$
\nabla^T_c(f(z))=J_cf(z)=J_zf(z)J_c(z)=J_zf(z)
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&0&\cdots&0\\
0 & x_2 & & \vdots\\
\vdots & & \ddots&0\\
0 & \cdots & 0 &x_n
\end{bmatrix}=J_zf(z)\text{diag}(x)
$$
Hence, $\nabla_c(f(z))=\text{diag}(x)J^T_zf(z)$.

Here is where I am not sure:
$\nabla_c(f(z))\mid_{c=[1,\dots,1]^T}=\text{diag}(x)J^T_zf(z)\mid_{c=[1,\dots,1]^T}=\text{diag}(x)J^T_xf(x)$. How one rigorously can show they are equal?

I suspect that $J^T_zf(z)\mid_{c=[1,\dots,1]^T}=J^T_xf(x)$ because considering the scalar $x$ and $c$ along with function $g=\sin(cx)$ one has $\frac{\partial \sin(cx)}{\partial c}|_{c=1}=x\cos(x)$.